# MVC how to relationship AspNetUsers with other tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, code-first

I need to make relationship 1-to -any between my model table to AspNetUsers table using code first. I've tried so many ways I saw in this site and none is working.

This is my table model (Play):

```
public class Play
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string PlayLink { get; set; }


    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PlayList")]
    public int? PlayListId { get; set; }
    public virtual PlayList PlayList { get; set; }

}
```

And this is the identiy model:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;
    }


    [ForeignKey("Organization")]
    public int OrgId { get; set; }
    public virtual Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Play> Plays { get; set; }
}
```

This is the error I'm getting when I'm trying to update database:

> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_dbo.Plays_dbo.AspNetUsers_UserId". The conflict occurred in database "playlisttestdb", table "dbo.AspNetUsers", column 'Id'.

There are many posts in this site related to this issue and I tried almost all but still nothing.

Comment: I assume that the `Plays` table already exists and has data and you're trying to add the user relationship in afterwards?

Comment: @DavidG exactly

Comment: So adding the relationship means adding a `UserID` column to the `Plays` table, but that will create is with `null` values. That's why you get the error you see above. What user do you want to assign to these existing plays?

Comment: What can I say @DavidG, you are my hero

Comment: Haha OK, but is your problem solved yet?

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much